# Is there any way to reduce the length of static variable from another class?

Tags: java

I have a `public class Helper` in another file that has a few `public static` variables declared. I'm wondering if it's possible to shorten the variable name so that I don't have to consistently use `Helper.<variable_name>` everywhere. It would be ideal if I could just use the variable name without the `Helper` prefix.

Comment: @CommuSoft You should learn about static imports then!

Comment: Static import allow you to access static variable of `Helper` class to another class without `Helper` instance. this will likely make code more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
import static a.b.c.Helper.<variable_name>;
```

where a.b.c is the package which contains the Helper class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static import:

```
// Class1.java
package test;
import static test.Class2.static_var;
public Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(static_var); // not Class2.static_var
    }
}

// Class2.java
package test;
public class Class2 {
    public static String static_var = "Hello";
}
```

Output from `java test.Class1`:

```
Hello
```

Wildcard imports also work:

```
import static test.Class2.*;
```

Note that you must specify the full package name in the static import declaration. It is not sufficient to `import test.Class2;` and then `import Class2.*;`.